# Scala - make method from List Companion Object

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-collections

I see that that `List.make` is getting called here
http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p12.scala

But I have solved the problem using `padTo` because make doesn't exist anymore

```
  def decode[A](listOfTuples: List[(Int, A)]): List[Any] = {
    listOfTuples flatMap {
      x => Nil.padTo(x._1,x._2)
    }
  }
```

So, have I got this wrong?

Comment: ~What about just: `case (x, y) => List(x, y)`~ - oh wait, that seems to do something different, can you explain what `make` used to do?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez    I think you've misunderstood the question. I am talking about the presence/absence of `List.make`here.

Comment: When you follow a tutorial, you should make sure that you use the same versions. This tutorial seems to use Scala 2.7. (It was written in 2009, and that was the current version then, so I believe that's the version that was used.) In particular, you are talking about a method of the collection framework here, and the collection framework has been completely re-written twice since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List.make` was deprecated since Scala 2.8.0 in favor of `List.fill`. Your approach using `padTo` is correct, it just isn't as intuitive.

```
def decode[A](listOfTuples: List[(Int, A)]): List[A] = {
  listOfTuples flatMap {
    x => List.fill(x._1)(x._2)
  }
}
```

Note that I replaced `Any` with the type parameter `A`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be to use `fill` method from list. The solution is shown below:

```
scala> val l1 = List((4, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2,'c'))
l1: List[(Int, Char)] = List((4,a), (1,b), (2,c))

scala> def decode[A](l: List[(Int, A)]): List[A] = {
     | l flatMap { e => List.fill(e._1)(e._2)}
     | }
decode: [A](l: List[(Int, A)])List[A]

scala> decode[Char](l1)
res60: List[Char] = List(a, a, a, a, b, c, c)
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok?

```
def decode[A](listOfTuples: List[(Int, A)]): List[A] = {
  listOfTuples flatMap { case (n, e) => 
    List.fill(n)(e)
  }
}
```